# Find/replace conditionally formatted cells

Tags: vba, excel, replace, conditional-formatting

I've been using a conditional format formula `=OR(B2=B1,B2=B3)` to highlight consecutive duplicates.  I then use format painter to copy the formula to all columns in my excel table.

I have set up a button that will, amongst other things, copy a workbook into a new workbook.  I now want to include the above formula in this macro.  My final objective is to replace all of the cells found with this formula with an asterisk (*).

I first tried to just pop the formula into the macro as a starting point -

```
For Each sh In Destwb.Worksheets
With sh.UsedRange.FormatConditions _
     .Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=OR(B2=B1,B2=B3)")

     .Interior.Color = RGB(198, 239, 206)

End With
Next sh
```

But this just makes a mess of seemingly randomly highlighted cells.  I'm not sure where I've gone wrong.  Even column B highlights are all wrong.  Could the header in B1 affect this?  It doesn't when I use the CF normally.  How can I expand the CF into all columns uniquely?

Finally, how do I go about working a replacement of formatted cells into this formula?  Or is there a quicker/easier way to meet this end-goal?

I didn't realise I could add custom text in that way.  That's moved me a good couple of steps forward.

Taking Balinti's suggestion into consideration I've tried a workaround.  I was making a couple of assumptions that turned out to be wrong.  I have been able to enter the CF into the Array of data that I have in my original workbook.  It's not as simple as putting it into a table, but by manually selecting the range in each column and inputting the CF I have made it work.

I also wasn't sure if the formatting would carry through to the new worksheet as I have used the Paste Special command to convert the array formula to values in the new sheet.  It does, however, carry the formatting across which is very handy.

It's not the perfect solution for me but it appears to be working so far.  I still need to test what happens when I change the date and get updated data.  It would still be interesting to know if I can move this formatting into my macro though.  Any tips?

Comment: Why wont you use save as another name and avoid this mess?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  My original workesheet is pulling data from an SQL server.  It updates automatically each day.  I hit a button and it creates a new workbook with some sheets and not others.  But I want the new workbook to automatically perform certain tasks that save time and effort for the operator as well as reduce human error

Comment: Why not add a custom number format of `_(\*_)` to the CF rule to get your asterisks?

Comment: Instead of copy it to another file, just make save as a new file name and then your formmating will be preserved

Comment: I had a think about that, but it won't work I'm afraid.  The data (very large amount) must be pulled from an SQL server (Wonderware Historian) using array formulas.  This, in part, allows it to update automatically.  I, therefore, cannot format the original worksheets as I require them.
Currently exploring Jeeped's suggestion...